# Numbered urn with replacement

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $n$ balls numbered $1,2..,n$. $w$ balls are drawn with replacement. What is the probability of getting ball number $i$ $a$ times, ball number $j$ $b$ times and ball number $k$ $c$ times, where $a+b+c=w$?

Each ball has the same probability $p=\frac{1}{n}$. I guess this is a multinomial problem, so:

$$\Pr(X_i=a, X_j=b, X_k=c) = \frac{w!}{{a!}{b!}{c!}}{p}^{a}{p}^{b}{p}^{c}$$

And what if $a+b<w$?

$$\Pr(X_i=a, X_j=b) = \frac{w!}{{a!}{b!}{(w-a-b)!}}{p}^{a}{p}^{b}{(1-p-p)}^{w-a-b}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That is okay.  Alternatively you could have left the probability as $1/n$ so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_i{=}a, X_j{=}b, X_k{=}w{-}a{-}b) =&~ \dfrac{w!}{a!~b!~(w{-}a{-}b)!~n^w}~[0\leqslant a,0\leqslant b,a+b\leqslant w] \\[2ex] \mathsf P(X_i{=}a, X_j{=}b) =&~\dfrac{w!~(n-2)^{w-a-b}}{a!~b!~(w{-}a{-}b)!~n^w}~[0\leqslant a,0\leqslant b,a+b\leqslant w] \end{align}$$